# I want to photograph in low light settings and make 11x15 enlargements, current smartphone not adequate

Tags: sensor, smartphone

I have $350 US dollars to spend and was looking at new smartphones with top criteria being picture quality (have newborn, need pics).

However, I read even sub $200 cameras have better performance than phones costing $600. Plus, as a dedicated appliance, longevity seems better as well.

Are there small form factor(but good sensor size) cameras under $350 that can best say iPhone SE or Google Pixal 4a?
Criteria:

1. Low light performance
2. "Speed performance"/anti-blur
3. 11x15 enlargements
4. Optical zoom

In optimal light conditions, and optimal settings (little one standing still), current smartphone adequate.

If so, I will likely purchase cheap smartphone ($99) and upto $350 camera instead.

Edit: Point and shoot cameras (say from Nikon) are viable alternative?

Comment: What is the low light situation? Indoor sports? Social events? Astronomy? Landscape?

Comment: @Rafael Indoor pictures of active baby and family.

Comment: When you say 11x15 enlargements, what is your unit of measure? Inches or centimeters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a second hand Nikon or Canon.  With Christmas just past there will be a flood of them on the market from people who got a snazzier camera from Santa.

In particular you want one with an f/1.8 f/1.6 or f/1.4 lens.  This will maximize your light gathering capability.  This won't have optical zoom, but most zoom lenses that come with with entry level cameras will be f/3.5 at best.  This is about 1/12 the light gather capability of an f/1.4.  When you can afford it there are some good f/2.8 (one stop faster) zooms.

Read reviews.  You may find that an older full frame 12 megapixel camera has better lowlight performance than an newer APC beginner camera.  In general larger sensor sizes will do better in low light.  Newer ones also do better, so there is a trade off.

Locally I found a Nikon 3300 with a f/1.8 lens for $425 Canadian, which would be under 300 US.

Try ebay also.

---

A commenter pointed out the 11x15 print size, which I didn't take into account.

No phone is going to give you acceptable sharpness at 11x15 even in good light conditions.

Indeed, if this is a solid criterion, then I suggest that you try renting a full frame camera, and an f/2.8 zoom.

300 dpi is about the coarsest you can go and not have visible dots.  For comparison color newsprint is about 150-180 dpi.  National Geographic is something like 600.  (These figures are dredged out of a very deep, but ancient box of trivia in my head.  Commenters will set me straight shortly.)

300 dpi * 11 inches means that the short dimension of your image has to be 3300 pixels.  20 Mpix will manage this, but you will have to crop tightly.

Comment: Just to note that for 11.25x15 (4:3 ratio) 300dpi prints you really need 15mp. I'd be looking for an APS-C with 24mp to allow for a bit of crop room, like the D3300 you mention.

Comment: Print media makes a difference too. 300 dpi is a good target for a glossy print, but it would be more than needed for a canvas print.

Comment: Could the Panasonic Lumix DMC-LX15 / Panasonic Lumix DMC-LX10 be an alternative, used they are about 300$ and they have a bright f1.4 - 2.8 lens as well as image stabilisation.

Comment: My bet is that you would find that the small sensor made for unacceptable noise in low light.  Borrow one, and try it.  Much depends on 'how low'

Comment: I have been noting online reading the difference between full frame and cropped. Seems like 11x15 is going to be a stretch. Renting interesting.